# my CSS background image is not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have uploaded the file in my git repository and copied the link and pasted here. Is there any certain method?

```css
html{
  background-image:url("https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url that you used (https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg) returns a HTML page containing (among other info) the target image itself. Just visit the URL and see. I know it might look a little bit strange at first sight but this is how GitHub works. So, because the url doesn't actually serve the image, you can't see the image rendered on your background.

If you want to get the image itself and not the HTML page, you must access the "raw" URL for the image which is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vindhya97/images/master/pinkbackground.jpg
Just use this URL instead of the original one.

But be careful with this approach of embedding images in web pages. Now your repository is public. But if you deploy the webapp on some server and then you make your repository private, most probably the users that access the webapp won't see the image.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this raw image URL [raw_background_img_src](https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg?raw=true) as the URL you are using will not work. See working example below:

```css
body { 
    background-image:url("https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg?raw=true");
}
```

```html
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: body{
  background-image: url("https://images.app.goo.gl/FrArwNnFp8MZQEAk8?raw=true");
}
I have tried this , taking image from google.. it is not displaying. Actually I'm new to this so I've been exploring a lot.

Comment: @Vindhya this is the image URL https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/pastel-oil-painting-canvas-background_53876-93729.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg, If you add exactly what you want then i can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You copied the page link, you should copy the image link:

page link (it's wrong):
https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg

image link (it's true):
[https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg?raw=true](https://github.com/vindhya97/images/blob/master/pinkbackground.jpg)

or

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vindhya97/images/master/pinkbackground.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You just should use [raw link](https://help.data.world/hc/en-us/articles/115006300048-GitHub-how-to-find-the-sharable-download-URL-for-files-on-GitHub) to image:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vindhya97/images/master/pinkbackground.jpg");
}
```